# How to make GCM only send out last message like APNS?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to make the GCM server only send out the last message when the device is offline? (Override all the messages when the device is offline, but just leave the last one) Like what APNS is doing?

I want to see if i can control it from the server side instead, but not using collapse_key from the Mobile.

Comment: collapse_key is the way to go. Why won't you use it?

Comment: collapse_key does exactly this, and you control it on the server

Comment: ooo because i thought Collapse_key is done on the mobile side? I can collapse the messages to just the last one for offline devices on the server?? I will check it out thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys i just re-read the GCM documents, i think i should use the collapse_key and define them on the php. "When you define a collapse key, when multiple messages are queued up in the GCM servers for the same user, only the last one with any given collapse key is delivered."